# Adding padding in call to Matplotlib's PdfPages

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a few figures that I'm saving to a PDF file with Matplotlib's PdfPages backend. Unfortunately some of my figures are being inserted into the PDF file with a good portion of the y axis labels truncated. How do I specify that additional space should be added to avoid the label truncation? I've tried invoking the subplot_adjust command and passing left= and pad= parameters to no avail.

Any additional suggestions are most welcome!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

When you save your pdf using `plt.savefig`, use bbox_inches and pad_inches parameters to specify padding:

```
plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,3.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```